# Display Sticky posts at the top of archive page

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to display sticky posts at top of archive page.when click to next page button, sticky posts will be shown at the top again so not for only first page.

also the sticky posts mustnt enter the other post loop.Sticky posts must shown only one time at the same time.

also sticky post's border color must be red.may I can change its style with google chrome tools if sticky posts has own class.

here is my archive page code:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<main role="main">
    <?php get_template_part( 'breadcrumb' );?>
    <section class="ulockd-service-details">
        <div class="container">
            <?php hekim_left_sidebar(); ?>
            <?php hekim_col_sidebar(); ?>
                <div class="row">

                    <?php if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php
                if ( $thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id() ) {
                       ?>
                    <div class="col-md-12 ulockd-mrgn1210">
                        <div class="ulockd-project-sm-thumb">
                            <img class="img-responsive img-whp" style="width: 368px; max-height: 580px;" src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(array(1100, 550)); ?>">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php
                }
                ?>
                    <div class="col-md-12 ulockd-mrgn1210">
                        <article class="ulockd-pd-content">
                            <div class="ulockd-bp-date">
                                <ul class="list-inline">
                                    <?php
                                    if ( class_exists( 'Redux' ) ) {
                                        global $redux_demo;
                                        if ($redux_demo['button-set-date-choose'] == 1)
                                        {
                                            ?>
                                            <li class="ulockd-bp-date-innner"><?php _e( 'On ', 'hekim' )?><a href="#"><span class="text-thm2"><?php the_time('j'); ?></span> / <?php the_time('F Y') ?></a></li>
                                            <?php
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            ?>
                                            <li class="ulockd-bp-date-innner"><?php _e( 'On ', 'hekim' )?><a href="#"><span class="text-thm2"><?php the_time(); ?></span></a></li>
                                            <?php
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        ?>
                                        <li class="ulockd-bp-date-innner"><?php _e( 'On ', 'hekim' )?><a href="#"><span class="text-thm2"><?php the_time(); ?></span></a></li>
                                        <?php
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                    <li class="ulockd-bp-comment"><a href="#"><span class="flaticon-nurse-head text-thm1"></span> <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></a></li>
                                    <li class="ulockd-bp-comment"><a href="#"><span class="flaticon-chat text-thm1"></span> <?php if (comments_open( get_the_ID() ) ) comments_popup_link( __( 'Leave your thoughts', 'hekim' ), __( '1 Comment', 'hekim' ), __( '% Comments', 'hekim' )); ?></a></li>
                                    <li class="ulockd-bp-comment"><a href="#"><span class="flaticon-black-check-box text-thm1"></span> <?php the_category(); ?></a></li>

                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <h3><?php the_title(); ?> </h3>
                            <p class="project-dp-one"><?php the_excerpt(); //html5wp_excerpt('html5wp_index'); // Build your custom callback length in functions.php ?></p>
                            <a class="btn btn-lg ulockd-btn-thm2" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php _e( ' Read More', 'hekim' )?></a>
                        </article>
                    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php else: ?>
                    <article>
                        <h2><?php _e( 'Sorry, nothing to display.', 'hekim' )?></h2>
                    </article>
<?php endif; ?>
                    <?php get_template_part( 'pagination' ); ?>
                </div></div><?php hekim_right_sidebar(); ?>
        </div></section>
                    <?php get_footer(); ?>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could exclude your sticky post from main query and add it separately on each page.

For excluding your sticky post add next code to your `function.php`:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'posts_filter' );
function posts_filter( $query ){
    // do, only if it main query on front page
    if( !$query->is_front_page() || !$query->is_main_query() ) return;

    // post__not_in should be an array
    $sticky_post_id = [ 1 ];
    // it will exclude post with passed id from query
    $query->set( 'post__not_in', $sticky_post_id );
}
```

Inside the function `posts_filter()`, as first step we check is it query on front page and is it main query (post query).

Second step - set id of sticky post. It should be an array. Also, you could keep id in your `global $redux_demo;` for change it easily in future.

Third step - edit query by adding property `post__not_in` and use array with our sticky post id as value. This property will exclude post with ids from array in result, so you get all your posts without sticky one.

Now, let's move to your archive page.
Here you should use custom loop for add your sticky page content to `archive page`:

```
$sticky_post_id = 1;
$query = new WP_Query( [
    'p' => $sticky_post_id,
] );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

        // Here your post block code with custom html if you need

    endwhile;
endif;

wp_reset_postdata();
```

First of all you should create new WP_Query object. As arguments, pass id of your sticky post.

By using loop you could use personal html for this block and add red borders as you need. Also, you could use same functions as in regular loop like `the_title()`, `the_excerpt()` etc.

When you close your custom loop, use `wp_reset_postdata()` for clear custom query and be able to use regular loop. So, use your code as before:

```
<?php if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    // Code of your loop for posts

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php else: ?>

    <article>
        <h2><?php _e( 'Sorry, nothing to display.', 'hekim' )?></h2>
    </article>

<?php endif; ?>
```